# Having trouble to find shortcut key to jtoolbar in swings?

Tags: java, swing

I dont have any clue about code , any help would be appreciated

I am uploading an image of requirements , you can see that for particular toolbar i want to implement all shortcut key available , but i dont have any clue , where to start

Comment: I voted to close this question

Comment: cough ... voted to close the question as well, but ... it's not as straightforward as I expected - can't seem to be able to revoke the closing, hmm.

Comment: where's the image you promised?

Comment: upvoted to try preventing the complete downfall :-) I'm curious to hear more details about the requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thought: "that's easy, RTFT", spitting out the first code snippet:

```
    Action action = new AbstractAction("clear text") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("triggered the action");
        }

    };
    action.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"));

    JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();
    bar.add(action);
    // set toolbar to frame and be happy
```

Guess what happens on pressing F1 ... right, nothing.

It turns out that buttons in a toolBar - unlike their menu counterpart - *do not* support accelerator keys by default. That's unexpected to me (anybody else?), and may have several reasons

- it's an oversight on part of the Swing team
- they are not supported by native applications as well

the second might well be the case as typically, the toolBar buttons kind of "double" menu items: that being the case, the accelerator is set on the menu item (and if everything has been set up correctly and the same action used in both) it is triggered auto-magically.

Now the question is, whether or not the OP has a menu/bar in his/her application as well. Complete answer depends on that: if so, simply use the same action as above

```
    menu.add(action);
```

If it's *really* a stand-alone toolBar, not backed by a menu, slightly more work is involved, basically as [outlined in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240740/shortcut-key-for-jbutton-without-using-alt-key) which is to explicitly add the keyBinding to the button added to the toolBar, something like:

```
    JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();
    JButton toolBarButton = bar.add(action);
    toolBarButton.getActionMap().put("myAction", action);
    toolBarButton.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            (KeyStroke) action.getValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY), "myAction");
```

If this is a standard requirement for a given context for many buttons, subclass JToolBar, override the add(Action) method and do it there after calling super:

```
    public class JXToolBar extends JToolBar {

         public JButton add(Action action) {
              JButton button = super.add(action);
              KeyStroke stroke = (KeyStroke) action.getValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY);
              if (stroke != null) {
                  // do the input/actionMap config here
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: +1, There is no visual way to display the accelerator on a button (unlike a JMenuItem), so I guess it makes sense not to have this as supported behaviour. Also agree the Action should be shared with a JMenuItem to get this default behaviour.

Comment: @camickr good point - the only way to show the accelerator is a (manually configured) tooltip. Which requires to move the mouse over it to see, so it's not a real visual clue - but might be needed for screen readers anyway

Comment: Just remembered that AbstractButton provides a `configurePropertiesFromAction` method which might be better to override to set the bindings (and tooltip?). JMenuItem currently overrides this method to set the accelerator.